# foreach loop not working with single result

Tags: php, foreach

I have got the following array stored in the variable `$details`:

```
[formats] => Array ( 
        [format] => Array ( 
                 [0] => Array ( 
                    [formatId] => 1 
                    [code] => High 
                    [price] => Array ( 
                           [0] => 0.00 
                           [1] => 0.00 
                           [2] => 0.00 
                           [3] => 0.00 
                           [4] => 0.00 ) ) 
                  [1] => Array ( 
                     [formatId] => 2 
                     [code] => Med 
                     [price] => Array ( 
                            [0] => 0.00 
                            [1] => 0.00 
                            [2] => 0.00 
                            [3] => 0.00 
                            [4] => 0.00 ) ) 
                   ) )
```

and I use the following code to loop trough this array

```
<? foreach ($details['formats']['format'] as $format)
     {
        echo $format['code'];
     }
?>
```

Which works fine, but then, sometimes there is only one result in the array and then it looks like this:

```
[formats] => Array ( 
        [format] => Array ( 
                    [formatId] => 1 
                    [code] => High 
                    [price] => Array ( 
                           [0] => 0.00 
                           [1] => 0.00 
                           [2] => 0.00 
                           [3] => 0.00 
                           [4] => 0.00 )
                   ) )
```

Unfortunally my for each loop does not work then, because it is only a single array. How can this be solved? I cannot change the array.

I can use while or for loops if that is required, but I have no idea how

Comment: Why is the array like that? You should be consistent in the number of dimensions. If there's just one format, make it an array with one element, don't pull it out of the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very crude method of approaching the problem would be to just fold an 'if' around it;

```
<? 
if (isset($details['formats']['format'][0])){
    foreach ($details['formats']['format'] as $format)
    {
        echo $format['code'];
    }
} else {
    echo $details['formats']['format']['code'];
}
?>
```

This only works if the result array is consistant and it will always return [0] on multiple results.

Comment: How come this works, since an array with a single element is still an array?

Comment: This works, the [0] will only be present on multiple results.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as well.

```
if ( is_array($details['formats']['format']) && array_key_exists("code", $details['formats']['format']) ) {
    echo $details['formats']['format']['code'];
} else if ( is_array( $details['formats']['format'] ) {
    foreach ($details['formats']['format'] as $format)
    {
        echo $format['code'];
    }
}
```